# Linux /etc/hosts content

Tags: linux, security

On our Linux machine we have found this content of /etc/hosts file:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost

# *********��������Ϊ360��ȫ��ʿΪ���߻�����ľ����������******************
127.0.0.1  yu.8s7.net
127.0.0.1  1.jopanqc.com
127.0.0.1  2.joppnqq.com
...
...
```

There are more than 20 similar lines in the file.

What is this? Is this an attack?

Thanks for any idea.

Zlaja

Comment: You should ask this kind of question on http://www.serverfault.com.

Comment: Thank you. I will do it.

Comment: Judging from [this ThreatExpert report](http://www.threatexpert.com/report.aspx?md5=093121189b5f46574d18d56e5f87f8b7), you've got malware, and the hosts file modifications themselves aren't all that important to the real problem, except that they prevent access to sites that describe how to get rid of the malware.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not related to programming.

Answer (score 1):

Looks suspicious because typically there won't be more than 2-3 entries pointing to 127.0.0.1. However, an attacker may not gain much by redirecting the domain name lookups to 127.0.0.1 - unless the attacker runs a local server to capture the requests targeted to those domains. Do you see any suspicious process with a listener socket open? If true then it is likely to be an attack. Also search the web for those domain names. If it is an attack you will find more information about it. If all these turn out to be negative then it may not be an attack.

Comment: We have edited /etc/hosts file. After while it has been changed again. I have found only Chinese or Japanese site with this content. Any of this address can not be load in browser.

Comment: Then very likely your server has been compromised. Don't trust any data from that server. Format it cleanly and re-install the OS and reconfigure. Do not copy any configuration file from this server to clean server because configuration file itself may have been injected with the attacker's payload. Going forward use an intrusion detection tool to ensure your server remains clean.

Comment: RaviH. You where right it is Likewise service that changes /etc/hosts

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that there is a security program (similar to [denyhosts](http://denyhosts.sourceforge.net/)) running on your server which automatically registers suspicious hostnames as `127.0.0.1` in order to ban accessing those hosts by name?

Comment: No. Interesting thhe header of /etc/hosts starts with                             `# Copyright (c) 1993-1999 Microsoft Corp.
#
# This is a sample HOSTS file used by Microsoft TCP/IP for Windows.`

Comment: It looks like Likewise service that changes /etc/hosts